# Push object into schema using push() and save()

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

For each POST request I am saving marker with user's coordinates to database. Each marker should be then assigned with a user.In my User schema I have a key "markers", where I would like to gather objects of type Marker. Whole POST request looks like this:

```
 router.post("/", function(req, res, next) {
  var decoded = jwt.decode(req.query.token);
  User.findById(decoded.user._id, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({
        title: "An error occurred",
        error: err
      });
    }
    var marker = new Marker({
      name: req.body.name,
      date: new Date(),
      latitude: req.body.lat,
      longitude: req.body.lng,
      user: user._id
    });
    marker.save(function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("ERRROR");
        return res.status(500).json({
          title: "An error occurred",
          error: err
        });
      }
      user.markers.push(result);
      user.save();
      res.status(201).json({
        message: "Saved message",
        obj: result
      });
    });
  });
});
```

I have no idea why all the time "markers" array is empty.

```
        {
            "_id": "5ad4d67962909c1784c6a069",
            "firstName": "test",
            "lastName": "test",
            "password": "$2a$10$E.yPFSG4eM/57Up8Se5QXe59upcURxUiofIKxrTkCKs1jfuS5PGnu",
            "email": "test@wp.pl",
            "__v": 0,
            "markers": []
        }
```

It seems like that lines not working properly (however *user* object and *result* printed in console showing proper data) :

```
 user.markers.push(result);
 user.save();
```

If it is important I am putting here also my User mongoose schema:

```
var schema = new Schema({
  firstName: { type: String, required: true },
  lastName: { type: String, required: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  markers: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Marker" }]
});
```

Could you please give me some advice here?

Comment: you are sending `result` as a response which should just be a `maker` document. No ?

Comment: here `res.status(201).json({
        message: "Saved message",
        obj: result
      });`

Comment: result is a marker, right. I printed it in console and I can see marker object.So it should be pushed to user.markers with push() and saved with save(), then, listing users should show array of pushed markers for each user.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey any ideas here?